# Centering remaining elements after display:none

Tags: css, responsive-design, flexbox, centering

Note: I am using Flexbox

When the screen is re sized I use "display:none" to remove some elements that will no longer fit as things size down, but once they are removed the elements that are still displayed no longer are horizontally centered in their columns.

For Example:     (this is not code it a simple illustration)

```
|-------------------------------|
|       |       |       |       |
|  1 2  |  1 2  |  1 2  |  1 2  |
|-------|-------|-------|-------|
```

Ex: Now after the "2" element has the attribute "display:none"
what is left is no longer centered horizontally.

```
|-------------------------------|
|       |       |       |       |
|  1    |  1    |  1    |  1    |
|-------|-------|-------|-------|
```

What is the proper way to keep this horizontally centered as I scale down and remove element "2"?

Comment: Flexbox acts funny depending on what browser you use and how you implement it. Please add your code and specify your browser so we can help you.

Comment: This should actually work pretty well by default if the original content was already centered, as `display:none` completely removes the element from rendering considerations. Therefore this question cannot be answered without code (as nearly always actually).

Comment: Thanks guys! You're clues helped me look in the right area. The element left behind "1" I had to apply "margin:auto;" to that.

Comment: Actually using "margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;" turned out to be better in my case this "margin:auto" cause that started to cause some vertical centering issues.

Comment: `margin: auto` is a good solution, but not really necessary. As mentioned above, centering should persist after `display: none` goes into effect.

Answer (score 3):

#### Option 1 - Flex Solution

To center items in flexbox – and keep them centered – you can use the [`justify-content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content) and [`align-items`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items) properties.

HTML

```
<article id="container">
    <section class="box>
        <span class="one">1</span>
        <span class="two">2</span>
    </section>
    <section class="box>
        <span class="one">1</span>
        <span class="two">2</span>
    </section>
    <section class="box>
        <span class="one">1</span>
        <span class="two">2</span>
    </section>
 </article>
```

CSS

```
#container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center; /* align flex items horizontally (in this case) */
    align-items: center; /* align flex items vertically (in this case) */
    height: 50px;
    background-color: lightgray;
    border: 2px dashed black;
}

section {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 50px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    span.two { display: none; }
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/q4t78s78/4/) (re-size window for effect)

---

#### Option 2 - text-align

Another method to keep content centered is with `text-align: center` on the parent.

HTML (same as above)

CSS

```
#container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center; /* align flex items horizontally (in this case) */
    align-items: center; /* align flex items vertically (in this case) */
    height: 50px;
    background-color: lightgray;
    border: 2px dashed black;
}

section {
    width: 50px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    border: 1px solid red;
    text-align: center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    span.two { display: none; }
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/q4t78s78/)

Answer (score 1):

One way is to remove the "2" element from the DOM completely using javascript, then flexbox will center the remaining elements.

```
var element2 = document.getElementById("element2");
element2.parentNode.removeChild(element2);
```

Another way is to set the "2" element to "position:absolute", then flexbox won't be able to move it and the remaining elements will center as if it weren't there.

```
#element2{
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
}
```